# Maven Parent Project to be both a parent and a library

Tags: java, maven

I have two separate Maven projects:

- Project A  (Library)
- Project B  (Client)

Here's the background:

- Project A declares certain third party dependencies in it's pom.xml.
- Project A is declared as a parent in Project B.
- Project A also serves as a general purpose library itself (has some public interfaces and associated implementation classes that perform some general purpose tasks.)

I'm trying to see if I can make Project B simply inherit the dependencies by declaring Project A as the parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>net.example.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

And also include Project A as a dependency to take advantage of all the library classes it supplies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.example.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here's the pom of the Library project Project A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <!- Other dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Notice that I'm packaging it as a pom. I've included the Maven Jar plugin but I'm trying to get the Maven install to properly generate the jar file and install both the pom and the jar artifact.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. If all you want is *dependencies*, then those are included transitively *anyway*, so it sounds like you're actually trying to do something other than what you explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an issue because

1. A parent project must be packaging=pom
2. To produce a jar you'll want packaging=jar